# HTML/CSS: Navigation bar stretches to fit, accommodates variable html

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm trying to get `li` elements in a `ul` to have equal width, and fit on one line, with CSS, without knowing how many `li`s there are when the CSSis made (i.e. dynamically generated HTML).

W3Schools has a navigation bar [example](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_navbar.asp), but it's fixed-width, and if you add another `li` rather scaling to fit, the whole layout gets thrown off.

This is their example:

CSS:

```
ul
{
  list-style-type:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  overflow:hidden;
}
li
{
  float:left;
}
a:link,a:visited
{
  display:block;
  width:120px;
  font-weight:bold;
  color:#FFFFFF;
  background-color:#98bf21;
  text-align:center;
  padding:4px;
  text-decoration:none;
  text-transform:uppercase;
}
a:hover,a:active
{
  background-color:#7A991A;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
<li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
<li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

Ideally, I would be able to add another `li` and the menu would still display great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even thought I hate this solution... if you really need it to work with just HTML/CSS and auto-update width, a table would do the trick.

Otherwise I would recommend just having some simple JS updates the widths for you. If you are adding the extra options via JS it would be easy to toss this in.

EDIT:  Actually, depending on your targeted browsers.  You could use the `display: table` stuff but it is limited to IE8+.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/scispear/egGSX/)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do this with javascript I guess...

you could use javascript to get the window width and the number of list items. If you have these you can assign a fixed width using javascript.

Comment: I was hoping I wouldn't have to do this... The ugly part is that JavaScript runs _after_ the page is loaded.

Comment: I fear there is no other solution... 
In normal case the user won't notice javascript changing the layout..